# MATLAB: Set points within plot polygon equal to zero

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I am currently doing some seismic modelling and processing in MATLAB, and would like to come up with an easy way of muting parts of various datasets.  If I plot the frequency-wavenumber spectrum of some of my data, for instance, I obtain the following result:

[image]

Now, say that I want to mute some of the data present here. I could of course attempt to run through the entire matrix represented here and specify a threshold value where everything above said value should be set equal to zero, but this will be very difficult and time-consuming when I later will work with more complicated fk-spectra.  I recently learned that MATLAB has an inbuilt function called `impoly` which allows me to interactively draw a polygon in plots.  So say I, for instance, draw the following polygon in my plot with the `impoly`-function:

[image]

Is there anything I can do now to set all points within this polygon equal to zero?  After defining the polygon as illustrated above I haven't found out how to proceed in order to mute the information contained in the polygon, so if anybody can give me some help here, then i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/50282-how-to-get-the-region-of-interest-using-impoly

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`createMask`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imroi.html#imroi-delete) function that's part of the `impoly` interface once you delineate the polygon in your figure.  Once you use create this mask, you can use the mask to index into your data and set the right regions to zero.

Here's a quick example using the `pout.tif` image in MATLAB:

```
im = imread('pout.tif');
figure; imshow(im);
h = impoly;
```

I get this figure and I draw a polygon inside this image:

[image]

Now, use the `createMask` function with the handle to the `impoly` call to create a binary mask that encapsulates this polygon:

```
mask = createMask(h);
```

I get this mask:

```
imshow(mask);
```

[image]

You can then use this mask to index into your data and set the right regions to 0.  First make a copy of the original data then set the data accordingly.

```
im_zero = im;
im_zero(mask) = 0;
```

I now get this:

```
imshow(im_zero);
```

[image]

---

Note that this only applies to single channel (2D) data.  If you want to apply this to multi-channel (3D) data, then perhaps a multiplication channel-wise with the **opposite** of the mask may be prudent.

Something like this:

```
im_zero = bsxfun(@times, im, cast(~mask, class(im)));
```

The above code takes the opposite of the polygon mask, converts it into the same class as the original input `im`, then performs an element-wise multiplication of this mask with each channel of the input separately.  The result will zero each spatial location that's defined in the mask over all channels.

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you so much.  This works perfectly.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Kristian my pleasure :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again - I also appreciate the update about multi-channel data!

Comment: Hi, sorry, I just have one small additional question regarding your answer.  What exactly is meant when you say the 'opposite' of the mask?  That the information contained in the original mask is now kept while everything else is masked?

Comment: @Kristian The original mask contains all of the points that are contained inside the polygon.  By the opposite, I mean those points that are **outside** of the polygon.  Those are the points you want to retain while the points inside the polygon are set to 0.  As such, by creating a mask that is the opposite, this means that all of the points in the polygon are 0, while the rest of the points are set to 1 so that doing a multiplication with this mask retains all of the information while zeroing the points inside the polygon.

Comment: Ah OK.  Yeah, that's what I thought.  It makes perfect sense :).  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Kristian - No problem!